# Why last value in a csv keeps repeating itself when reading from

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

Here is a look at the function I have been messing with for a day now. For some reason it writes the last value in the csv over and over as opposed to parsing through the rows. I threw in some print statements and it appears the row contents are correctly writing to the array but are being over written by the last value. Any help would be amazing, thanks.

```
public int csvCombine(ArrayList <Indexstruct> todaysCSV, int totalconvo, String date) throws IOException{   
String rows = null;
Indexstruct templist=new Indexstruct();
String [] rowArray= new String [2];

FileReader fr = new FileReader(date + ".csv");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

rows= br.readLine();
rowArray=rows.split(",");
totalconvo+=Integer.parseInt(rowArray[0]);      //Reads in total amount of words spoken and adds it to the CSV value of words spoken
final int csvSize=Integer.parseInt(rowArray[1]);            //Read in size of csvList 

for(int count=0; count<csvSize-1; count++){
    rows = br.readLine();
    rowArray = rows.split(",");                         // Reads lines into an array, takes array values and places them into an object of type indexStruct to write into ArrayList
    templist.numOfUses=Integer.parseInt(rowArray[1]);   //sets object num of uses
    templist.Word=rowArray[0];                          //sets object word
    todaysCSV.add(count, templist);                     //adds object to csv ArrayList
    }   
br.close();
return totalconvo;
}
```

Comment: ... or you can ignore the answers to your question.

Answer (score 1):

All you're currently doing is adding the same templist object over and over again, and so it makes sense that all data is the same. You need to create a new templist object (whatever type it is) with each iteration of the for loop.

i.e.,

```
for(int count=0; count < csvSize-1; count++) {
    rows = br.readLine();
    rowArray = rows.split(",");                         
    int useCount = Integer.parseInt(rowArray[1]);   
    String word = rowArray[0];                      

    // assuming a type called TempList with a constructor that looks like this
    todaysCSV.add(count, new TempList(useCount, word));    
}
```